# Calculate $E[X_i^2]$ of a function related to binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this problem:

Suppose that we have $n$ independent observations of an event $A$, $p=P(A)$. We define $$X_i = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if A happens in the i-th observation } \\ 0 & \text{ if A doesn't happen in the i-th observation } \end{cases}$$

Calculate $E[X_i]$ and $E[X_i^2]$.

My reasoning is that if we have independent observations with a probability $p$ then we have the binomial distribution. However, I still don't get how to calculate the second expected value. In the case of the fist one, it is as simple as thinking that we are asked for the expected value of just one event of the series of events, thus it's given by the problem and $E[X_i]=p$. For the second expected value I don't understand how could we calculate it, the only thing I get id that since $0<p<1$ then $p=\frac{1}{k}$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $E[X_i^2]\leq \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{k} < 1$ and we can only say $E[X_i^2]$ is bounded by 1. Any help for calculating this second expected value is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1^{2}=1$ and $0^{2}=0$ it follows that $X_i^{2}$ is same as $X_i$. Hence $EX_i^{2}=EX_i=p$.